# How to make an executable python tkinter file with a connection to a sqlite3 database

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter, pyinstaller

I have made a simple CRUD database program like a very simple inventory system. It is able to read from database, update the database, delete things from database and etc. by doing  queries to the SQLite3 database. Now, I would like to make it executable so that I could share it to users for them to try out the program.

By now, I have tried pyinstaller with such code:
 `pyinstaller --onefile --add-data "database.db:." inventory.py`

It successfully compiled the program. However, when I execute the executable file, comes an error in the terminal saying `sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: items_list` and it immediately close the program.

Here is the code inside the program for me to connect to the sqlite3 database:

```
db = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
cursor = db.cursor()
```

and for me to display the items in the treeview, I used:

```
def update(rows):
    tree.delete(*tree.get_children())
    for i in rows:
        tree.insert('', 'end', value=i)
...
query = 'SELECT ItemName, CardNo, StockCount FROM items_list'
cursor.execute(query)
rows = cursor.fetchall()
update(rows)
```

Is there a way where I could combine the .py file with the .db file and make an executable single program? Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Comment: Not sure you want to embed your database in the .exe: no change is going to be saved. Every time you are going to run the exe it will start with the same database data you had when building the exe

Comment: @EricMathieu hmmm so what should i do if i want to make the program be able to connect with the sqlite3 database?

Comment: I know nothing about sqlite3 database but I can tell you that nothing prevents you from accessing a database not embedded with the exe

Comment: @EricMathieu the thing is that im confused because there's no error with the connection but when the .exe runs the queries for the sqlite it doesnt read it properly (sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: items_list). i've tried going through the internet and doesnt find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have written similar Inventory type scripts that all work with a sqlite database. All variables aside. I used `pyinstaller.exe --onefile --windowed` as command. When using Windows 10, it puts in in the `C:\...\dist` directory. I copied the database to the same path as the `.exe` file(s) with all imported scripts used in the `.exe` file and it accesses the respective database accordingly. Also basing it on other variables like to install the respective programs. (I just did it to be sure I do not run into any issues regarding alpha testing.) Then also depending on when the code, updates the `.db` file accordingly. (This method worked for me when I encountered similar issues)